# gformula package returns error in intervention

Tags: r

I am using the `gformula` package in R to estimate the effect of a natural treatment history on my dependent variable. My data is unbalanced panel data, with some missing values on the DV and its covariates.
When I try to run the following code:

```
gformula(obs_data = dt, outcome_type = 'continuous_eof', id= 'country_iso3', time_name = 'recode_year', seed = 1234, outcome_name = 'newbusiness', covnames = c('totalnumber', 'nkillwound', 'GDPppp'), covtypes = c('zero-inflated normal', 'zero-inflated normal' ,"normal"), intvars = c('totalnumber', 'nkillwound'), interventions = c('natural', 'natural'), histvars = list(c('totalnumber', 'nkillwound', 'GDPppp'), c('totalnumber', 'nkillwound', 'GDPppp')), histories = c(lagged, cumavg), covparams = list(covmodels = c(totalnumber ~ lag1_totalnumber + cumavg_totalnumber, nkillwound ~ lag1_nkillwound + cumavg_totalnumber, GDPppp ~ lag1_GDPppp + lag1_totalnumber + lag1_nkillwound + cumavg_totalnumber + cumavg_nkillwound)), ymodel = newbusiness ~ nkillwound + GDPppp + lag1_totalnumber + lag1_nkillwound)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in intervention[[i]][[1]](newdf, pool, intvar[i], intvals = NULL,  : 
  attempt to apply non-function
In addition: There were 19 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

17 out of the 19 warnings are:

```
In stats::rnorm(x, mean, est_sd) : NAs produced
```

I have read the accompanying article to the package as well as the `help gformula` but I do not know if I can fix the code or not.

Comment: do the examples from the documentation run okay? https://rdrr.io/cran/gfoRmula/man/gformula.html

Comment: Yes, the code for 'Estimating the effect of treatment strategies on the mean of a continuous end of follow-up outcome' works fine.